# dynamically pass the columns to select() in python postgresql

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Below code works fine

```
table = Table('user_data',metadata,autoload=True,autoload_with=conn)
stmt = select([table.columns.user_id,table.columns.username])
results = conn.execute(stmt).fetchall()
print(results)
```

But when i try to pass the columns as list (from postresql db) it fails

```
cols = get_table_cols() -- it returns a list -> [table.columns.user_id,table.columns.username]
stmt = select(cols )
results = conn.execute(stmt).fetchall()
print(results)
```

Error:

```
 sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Textual column expression 'table.c.username' should be explicitly declared with text('table.c.username'), or use column('table.c.username') for more specificity
```

Kindly provide inputs on the same

Comment: Can you provide the error logs?

Comment: added error details. tried with column () and text() but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just recently experienced something similar to this. Keep in mind my engine had the 'Future' attribute set to True (in case this doesn't work for you)

I can't remember why simply unpacking the list like this didn't work (which it might in your case)

```
stmt = select(*cols)
```

But this ended up being my solution

```
cols = get_table_cols()
#assuming cols does return a list
stmt = select(*[c for c in cols])

#alternatively you can get the columns directly from the table object
#stmt = select(*[c for c in table.c])
results = conn.execute(stmt).fetchall()

#session.execute(stmt).all() -> what I did for ORM

print(results)
```

If you are using declarative classes for ORM, the table object can instead be accessed with

```
ClassName.__table__
```